Seeking Guidance on Synchronizing Indexing Data Between Two Solr Cloud Clusters in Different Regions(east us & central us)
I'm currently working with two Solr Cloud clusters located in different regions, and I'm looking for advice on how to synchronize the indexing data between them. Can anyone help me identify the best approach for achieving this synchronization?
Any help is Appreciated.

Any updates team?
